# Is there an equivalent to mysql IN function in sql-server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

On the frontend, I have an array with ID's. I want to request the Rows with These ID's. In MySQL, there is a function IN(). And I want to use a similar function to that in my query. Is there such a function in SQL-Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same in sql server as well. Btw in is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Sorry I've searched for this question. But the documentation was showing queries in the IN operator. Which confused me. Again sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Do you understand why you can have a query in the `IN` operator?

Comment: At first sight I didn't. But now I do. My query works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the same in both MySQL and SQLServer

```
SELECT column1, colum2
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE column1 IN (5, 8, 10)
```